# Proof of mean for a log normal distribution

Tags: statistics

I've got the following integral $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\mathrm{exp}\!\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \mathrm{d}x$$

And I'd like rewrite this into something involving an integral that says $\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ instead.

So, apparently, I can simply make the "change of variable"-substitution by saying $y = x - \mu$ and then integrate over $\mathrm{d}y$, which would give me the integral I wanted. But I am not sure I understand what's going on here.... are the two integrals the same? How does the original relate to the other? Are we simply using the technique of integration by substitution here (since $y' = 1$, so multiplying that on would do nothing)?

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as this: substitution $y=x-\mu$. The integral does not change if you integrate on $]-\infty,+\infty[$ (notice you didn't write the bounds). But here you integrate the pdf of a normal distribution, this has nothing to do with the mean of a log-normal distribution, so why this title?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I put the log normal in the title, but forgot to mention that I need to do this step in other to prove what the mean of the log normal distribution is.